# How to display Ajax jquery Symfony3.2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I start with ajax with symfony 3.2 and I have a small test sum of the two numbers, the query has been sent well but it does not show, because the status is 200 OK(Inspected google chrome) but does not display. thank you for helping me

this my Controller:

```html
/**
     * @Route("/cal",name="cal_page")
     */
    public function ajaxAction(Request $request)
    {
        $num1=$request->query->get('nbr1');
        $num2=$request->query->get('nbr2');

        $som=$num1+$num2;
        var_dump($som);

        

        return $this->render('ProjetBundle:Default:ajax.html.twig',array('som'=>$som));
    }
```

view:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>Nombre1</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="" id="num1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Nombre2</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="" id="num2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Resultat</td>
   <td><span id="resultat"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   
   <td colspan="2"><input type="button" name="" id="bttn" value="somme"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

JS:

```html
{% block javascripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( "#bttn" ).click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var nbr1 = $('#num1').val();
                var nbr2 = $('#num2').val();
                if (isNaN(nbr1)|| isNaN(nbr2)) {
                    alert('nbr1 ou nbr2 number');
                }
                else{
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'GET',
                        data:{nbr1:nbr1,nbr2:nbr2},
                        url:'{{path('cal_page')}}',
                        success:function(data){
                            $('#resultat').html(data);
                            console.log('aiza ah');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
{%endblock%}
```

Maybe it's at the twig level that there is something that does work, thank in advance for your help

Comment: Did you have enabled jquery file before this code?

Comment: yes, Imanali Mamadiev, I have to put it where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to actually tell your twig template to show your answer, it won't just magically appear.

For example, to place it in your  element with id `resultant`, you could do the following. The `|default` filter will take care of the case where `som` variable is empty.

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Nombre1</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="" id="num1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Nombre2</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="" id="num2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Resultat</td>
        <td><span id="resultat">{{ som|default }}</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td colspan="2"><input type="button" name="" id="bttn" value="somme"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have another problem ehymel, because when I click the result does not display directly I have to click on _profiler symfony so that the result is displayed